# Python: How to retain headers from one file and append it to another

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file `data.csv` and i have divided this file into 2 files `test.csv` and `train.csv` by the following code:

```
import csv
import random

with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as data:
    with open('test.csv', 'w') as test:
        with open('train.csv', 'w') as train:
            test_writer = csv.writer(test)
            train_writer = csv.writer(train)
            for line in csv.reader(data):
                if random.random() > 0.85:
                     test_writer.writerow(line)
                else:
                    train_writer.writerow(line)
```

this code though worked fine but the headers were present in `test.csv` but no headers were found in `train.csv` any way to update the code and get the headers in both the files?

Comment: I think `next(data)` will consume one line, then move to file pointer to the next line. But you save that line to a variable, so it seems weird to me that `header` would change state between those two lines that you write it.

Comment: @cricket_007 the main concern is that i only want to get the headers in both the files. if there be an efficient method to do it?

Comment: You code works for me using (Python3.4.2)

Comment: Like Jerome here says, I don't see why this wouldn't work

Comment: Don't you have a leading empty line before the headers line? What if you add a `print(header)` before test.write and after train.write?

Comment: i am using python 2.7 though. and headers are not present in train.csv file

Comment: @Jérôme i don't have any leading empty line before the headers line. as the CSV i obtain is from a website. I don't want to make alterations in the CSV file.

Comment: You say you have `test.csv` and `train.csv` but do not show what `test_output` and `train_output` variables actually contain. Do you get any rows in train.csv?

Comment: This works on python 2.7

Comment: Just checking that you don't by accident actually open test.csv twice.

Comment: I meant add `print(header)` before `test.write` and after `train.write` to see what actually is in `header`?

Comment: updated the code for best references

Comment: After the edit just made it is clear why the other file will receive the header and the other won't: the code starts reading the csv.reader line by line, writes at random the lines to either of the csv.writers. The headers is just a line like any other.

Comment: okay. so any change in the code suggested?

Comment: Well, you just removed the line that read `header = next(data)`, no surprise it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question actually would've worked, but after the edit it became clear what the issue at hand is: the csv.reader is read line by line and written at random to either of the csv.writers.

You need to read the header first like you did in your 1. example:

```
import csv
import random

with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as data, \
        open('test.csv', 'w') as test, \
        open('train.csv', 'w') as train:
    test_writer = csv.writer(test)
    train_writer = csv.writer(train)
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    header = next(reader)
    test_writer.writerow(header)
    train_writer.writerow(header)
    for row in reader:
        if random.random() > 0.85:
            test_writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            train_writer.writerow(row)
```